# Web based LAN devices monitoring dashboard tool

Tags: open-source, network-monitor, dashboard

I'd like to be able to monitor the devices on my LAN (aka connected to my router). I just changed ISP and the default router is a bit lackluster in features, so I wanted to install some sort of automatic LAN scanning tool on one of my Raspberry Pis that monitors the devices that connect to the router so I can detect new devices, assign them a human readable name, and get information such as local IP and MAC address. Ideally with a dashboard or something like that (like Dashlinux or PiHole's dashboard). In case I detect some unknown device I can block it in the router's config.

Is there something like this?